# Plotting events as a single bar barplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have done some network testing, and have ended up with a CSV-file representing the dropouts in connection on this format:

```
seqstart,seqend,start date,start time,end date,end time,latency(ms)
23,58,20/02/2023,17:38:12.524622,20/02/2023,17:38:30.024620,17.499998
83,144,20/02/2023,17:38:42.524619,20/02/2023,17:39:13.024569,30.49995
177,187,20/02/2023,17:39:29.524621,20/02/2023,17:39:34.524625,5.000004
188,217,20/02/2023,17:39:35.024591,20/02/2023,17:39:49.524621,14.50003
4011,4044,20/02/2023,18:11:26.524624,20/02/2023,18:11:43.024625,16.500001
4131,4163,20/02/2023,18:12:26.524627,20/02/2023,18:12:42.524625,15.999998
4191,4223,20/02/2023,18:12:56.524627,20/02/2023,18:13:12.524627,16.0
4461,4523,20/02/2023,18:15:11.524626,20/02/2023,18:15:42.524626,31.0
16671,16733,20/02/2023,19:56:56.524634,20/02/2023,19:57:27.524628,30.999994
```

I want to illustrate this on a format similar to this:
[image: Wanted illustration]

Together with ChatGPT I managed to get this, with the code:

[image: Current illustration]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load the CSV file into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

# Combine start-date and start-time into a single datetime column
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start date'] + ' ' + df['start time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')

# Combine end-date and end-time into a single datetime column
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end date'] + ' ' + df['end time'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')

# Calculate the duration of each event in minutes
df['duration'] = (df['end'] - df['start']).dt.total_seconds() / 60

# Sort the events by start time
df = df.sort_values(by='start')

# Create a horizontal bar chart with start time on the y-axis and duration on the x-axis
plt.barh(df['start'], df['duration'], height=0.5)

# Set the y-axis label to be the start date
plt.ylabel('Start Date')

# Set the x-axis label to be the duration in minutes
plt.xlabel('Duration (minutes)')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

How can I alter this code to get the illustration showed at the top? I have tried asking ChatGPT even further, but it did not give me any results

Optionally - Since the data is taken over a period of days. To make it more readable, maybe it could be possible to display 6 or 12 hours on the X-axis, and then make a new line/pipe? Like shown below:

[image: Optionally]

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you manage to rebuild your dataframe to contain for each day alternating the duration without dopouts and the duration with dropouts. The days with fewer dropouts than the day with most dropouts are filled with `np.nan` values. Note, All durations per row should add up to 24h.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import cycle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [10, 2, 1, 1, 10],
    [10, 3, 11, np.nan, np.nan],
], index=["day1", "day2"])

color_cycles = cycle(["green", "red"])
colors = [next(colors) for _ in range(len(df[0]))]
df.plot.barh(stacked=True, color=colors)
plt.legend([])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. If I am to proceed with this approach, I will have to do some work to automate the process and use some loops, as the dataset I am working with is approx 1 million lines in total.

Comment: A much easier way to go is generating an empy image (array) and then fill colors in the dropout times. If that is okay for you I can show you how its done, if you provide some lines of sample data in dataframe format. However, you wont have a plot figure but an image instead

Comment: That would be greatly appreciated. I edited the original post with more sample data

Comment: I created a new answer that solves this with images. I then embedded the image into a pyplot figure for labels and ticks. I hope, this is what you need :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a version that works with images.

Please note: There is a minimum error width, because your errors are so short in duration, that they will be hardly ever visible. Adjust to your needs. Also: If an error starts at day one and ends at day two, the error is only shown for day one.

[image: result]

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(
    "data.csv",
    parse_dates=["start date", "end date"]
)

# add new column for start
df["start minute of the day"] = df["start time"].apply(
    lambda x: timedelta(
        hours=int(x.split(":")[0]),
        minutes=int(x.split(":")[1]),
        seconds=float(x.split(":")[2])
    ).total_seconds() / 60
)

# add new column for end
df["end minute of the day"] = df["end time"].apply(
    lambda x: timedelta(
        hours=int(x.split(":")[0]),
        minutes=int(x.split(":")[1]),
        seconds=float(x.split(":")[2])
    ).total_seconds() / 60
)

# list of (ordered) distinct days
days = list(sorted(df["start date"].unique()))


# create an image
bar_height = 20  # px
minute_width = 1  # px
color_green = np.array([0, 191, 84])
color_red = np.array([255, 20, 64])
minimum_error_width = 50  # reduce to your need

img_width = minute_width * 24 * 60  # one full day
img_height = bar_height * len(days)
img = np.ones((img_height, img_width, 3), np.uint8)

# fill all green
img = img * color_green

for img_row_idx, day in enumerate(days):
    df_filtered = df[df['start date'] == day]
    for _, row in df_filtered.iterrows():
        # if you choose other intervals than minutes, adjust round accordingly
        start_index = int(row["start minute of the day"])
        end_index = int(row["end minute of the day"])
        end_index = min(max(end_index, start_index+minimum_error_width), img_width)
        # fill red
        img[
            img_row_idx*bar_height:(img_row_idx+1)*bar_height,
            start_index:end_index
        ] = color_red

plt.imshow(img)

plt.yticks(
    ticks=np.linspace(bar_height/2, bar_height*len(days)-bar_height/2,  num=len(days)),
    labels=[str(d)[:10] for d in days]
)
plt.xlabel("minute of day")
plt.ylabel("day")
plt.savefig("output.jpg")
```